# iFrame New Google Maps

Tags: google-maps

I tried insert on iframe google maps in this mode:

```
<iframe width=883 height=394 frameborder=0 scrolling=no marginheight=0 marginwidth=0 src=https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=it&amp;geocode=&amp;q=" + lat + "," + longi + "&amp;aq=&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;t=m&amp;z=" + Settings.Default["zoom"].ToString() + "&amp;output=embed></iframe>";
```

but it is the old map and not new map..

Like this for new map: http://www.netip.de/

How to use the new map iframe?